# "rails generate" does not seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I got rails installed on  my system. I have been trying to create a model for my application, but it doesn't seem to work. I found a question which was of the same nature and i even tried to change the rails file in app/bin/rails: but to no avail.

Comment: what are you running? and what error are you getting?

Comment: Can just check rails version your using 'rails -v'

Comment: There shouldn't be an app/bin/rails unless you created it. By default that file goes into bin/rails.

Comment: the version is 4.0.2

Comment: I created an app by typing in, "rails new MyApp", it didn't work the way it is supposed to. I mean, it does create the entire directory with its sub-directories and files, but the moment I wish to create a model, which i have mentioned above, it doesn't do so.